# Algebra while solving differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve DE: $$y'' + 2y' + 5y = x + 4$$

I have the correct general solution 
$$y(x) = c_1\,e^{-x}\cos(2x) + c_2\,e^{-x}\sin(2x)\ .$$

So I take my 'guess' , take a couple of derivatives, and plug in for the equation $$2A +5(Ax + B) = x + 4$$

But at this point I'm stuck on solving for the constants. I attempted in several times but I'm just getting a jumbled mess. I realize that this is probably simple algebra I'm struggling with here

Comment: Do you have some initial conditions?

Comment: What is your guess?

Answer (score 6):

You need your equation to hold for **all** $x$, right? Then the parts that depend on $x$ must be equal ($5Ax = x$) and the parts that do not depend on $x$ must be equal; thus $A$ and $B$ must satisfy

$$
5A = 1 \\
2A + 5B = 4.
$$

Can you solve for $A$ and $B$ from here?

Answer (score 0):

The ansatz for $y_p = A x + B$ put in the DE gives 
$2A + 5(Ax + B) = x + 4$ where you compare coefficients for $x^k$, here $x^1=x$ and $x^0=1$, on both sides of the expanded equation. Finally $y = y_h + y_p$.